# How to Unregister or Update Registered SharePoint app

Tags: sharepoint-apps

I have an App to be used in my SharePoint tenant. From App developer I got the Client ID, Client Secret,  App domain, return Url.

During my app registration through Appregnew.aspx, I have used wrong return url, and client secret. Now if I click on that app, it throws me error "An error occurred....".

To Use that App, I need to update my registered App with my correct client secret and return url. I am not finding any way .. How to Update or Unregister the SharePoint App.

Comment: this enables you to view the site collection apps in a list form https://**.sharepoint.com/sites/[sitename]/_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the AzureAD PowerShell [module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/AzureAD).

Then run the following commands to remove your registered SharePoint app:

```
Connect-AzureAD
$app = Get-AzureADServicePrincipal | Where-Object {$_.AppId -eq "your client ID"}
Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -ObjectId $app.ObjectId
```

After that you can follow the instructions in Santosha Epilis answer.

Comment: Here is also an exaplanation about how to do it from the graphical interface https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198926/delete-registered-app-in-sharepoint

Answer (score 7):

To get your app registration details use below link

***{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx***

Then update your details using below link with existing Client ID(do not use generate client ID and client secret)

***{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx***

This will update your app registration details for existing client ID.

Use link for more details 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj687469.aspx

Comment: This approach does not work for SharePoint Online (as of today, at least). The AppRegNew.aspx throws some exception ("Something went wrong").

Comment: Jen-Ari you are correct. I tried the approach by Santosh and it has returned error.

Answer (score 5):

Not official/documented way but it works for me for SharePoint Online

1) I have installed [Azure AD PS](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj151815.aspx#bkmk_installmodule)

2) Then run the following PS script

    `Connect-MsolService
    $appPrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName client_id
    Remove-MsolServicePrincipal -ObjectId $appPrincipal.ObjectId`

3) Then go to **{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/appinv.aspx** and try lookup app by client_id. You can get *Unexpected error* or *no info(like new id)*

4) Then go to **{SiteUrl}/_layouts/15/appregnew.aspx** and register app again with same client id

Comment: You need to perform this operation under tenant admin.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution as well, for doing the same task but [through the azure portal](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/198926/delete-registered-app-in-sharepoint)

Take a look ;)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:
Install-Module MSOnline
Connect-MsolService
$appPrincipal = Get-MsolServicePrincipal -ServicePrincipalName client_id
Remove-MsolServicePrincipal -AppPrincipalId $appPrincipal.AppPrincipalId

Or, you will need to go to your Azure AD portal.
Click on the Azure Active Directory portal.
Search for the Enterprise Applications => All applications (remove all filters)
Filter by All applications and by your Shp App Id.